# Having Pandas astype give type conditionally

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a column within my dataframe for each month that contains numbers unless there's an invalid value, in which case it shows a text error.

Using `df.astype({'Jan':'int32'}).dtypes` fails because of the text error within the Jan column.

Is there a way to export the dataframe to Excel with the numeric data as int32, while not yielding an error because of the text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can drop or replace the text values and then convert normally.

An example with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to drop the values:

```
df = df.loc[df['Jan'].str.isnumeric()]
df.astype({'Jan': 'int32'}).dtypes
```

Or to replace:

```
df.loc[~df['Jan'].str.isnumeric(), ['Jan']] = 0
df.astype({'Jan': 'int32'}).dtypes
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into trying that. Ideally, I'd like to keep the text errors in the output as well, but that seems to be a big challenge.